# App.vue constructed using webpack does not seem to mount to index.html

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, webpack

This is a very simple demo, but it doesn't get the expected output.

```
webpack.common.js
```

```js
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');

function resolve(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: resolve('/dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: file => (
          /node_modules/.test(file) &&
          !/\.vue\.js/.test(file)
        ),
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /(\.css$)/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl(us)?$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
            options: {
              module: true
            }
          },
          'stylus-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 8192
          }
        }]
      }

    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true
    }),
    new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
      clientsClaim: true,
      skipWaiting: true
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin()

  ]

};
```

```
webpack.dev.js
```

```js
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
function resolve(dir) {
    return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: resolve("/dist")
    }
});
```

```
index.html
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<body>
    <noscript>
        This is your fallback content in case JavaScript fails to load.
    </noscript>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
main.js
```

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = true

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

```
app.vue
```

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      message: "Hello Vue.js!"
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Finally, the result is this
 
[image]

I observed that the app.js in the built project is code with App.vue, but I don't know why they don't work.
And the terminal did not prompt an error.
If you want to know more details, you can comment below.
Finally, thank you for being able to answer this question.

Comment: Hello everyone, I found that I have solved this problem. I don't know why, I can mount App.Vue normally after I turn on the hot reload function.

Comment: `const webpack = require("webpack")
 new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
`Add the above two lines of code to webpack.common.js.